# Layout shop page: resize images and columns

Tags: plugins, images, shortcode, css, sidebar

I've added the "WooCommerce Products Filter" plugin on my ebook store wordpress theme. I've prepared a custom page for my shop page and built the sidebar with the filter with the WP Bakery Page Builder plugin. Everything works but the images of the books and the columns. Take a look to the URL: https://www.editorialufv.es/prova-maledetta/ Here a screenshot of the WP editor 
[image: Screenshot]

As you can see I've used the shortcode of the plugin. All the shortcodes are here: https://www.woocommerce-filter.com/shortcode/woof_products/

Why the image is so enormous and why the books aren't on columns? Any clue. I'm completely lost. Here the file page.php that is using my theme in this shop custom page:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="content">
    <!-- Sidebar With Content Section -->
    <?php
    $ebookstore_content_raw = json_decode( ebookstore_decode_stopbackslashes( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ebookstore_content', true ) ), true );

    $ebookstore_content_raw = ( empty( $ebookstore_content_raw ) ) ? array() : $ebookstore_content_raw;

    $ebookstore_theme_option = get_option( 'ebookstore_admin_option',array() );

    if (isset( $ebookstore_theme_option['book-search-style'] ) && $ebookstore_theme_option['book-search-style'] == 0) {

    } else {

        echo '<div class="margin-minus-50-top">';

        echo ebookstore_get_search_form_result();

        echo '</div>';

    }

    if (!empty( $ebookstore_content_raw )) {

        echo '<div class="vc-wrapper container">';

        while (have_posts()) {
            the_post();

            if (has_shortcode( get_the_content(), 'vc_row' )) {

                echo ebookstore_content_filter( get_the_content(), true );

            }

        }

        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="pagebuilder-wrapper">';

        ebookstore_show_page_builder( $ebookstore_content_raw );

        echo '</div>';

    } else {

        echo '<div class="container">';

        $default['show-title'] = 'enable';

        $default['show-content'] = 'enable';

        echo ebookstore_get_default_content_item( $default );

        echo '</div>';

    } ?>

</div><!-- content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing any form off styling for your columns woof does not add column styling it relies on your theme [image: woof documentation]

and in your css you have no stylings for columns[image: css]

Comment: This sounds like a bad news. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: .product {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 18px;
    height: 430px;
}

this css will show your products in a grid

Comment: this is not the cleanest answer UI wise due to you have some products that have very long titles

Comment: It works!!!! Thank you very much Brad! It works perfectly. I've lost so many hours looking for an answer. You've made me really happy. Thanx!

Comment: no problem, im glad this helped